Which role is responsible for performing `ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT` in PostgreSQL
In PostgreSQL I create table A referencing table B by FK with constraint option ON DELETE UPDATE SET DEFAULT. If the referenced record from table B is deleted, the physical change of the original FK for the default value is apparently done by the "system role" (in my case postgres)
Triggers on table A prevent editing when column is_locked is True. Based on the described role switching, I expect that I can let the change happen (even with is_locker==True if current_role = 'postgres'.
However this only works when the trigger is "BEFORE UPDATE" and not "AFTER UPDATE". The moment the records get physically updated, the DB changes the executing role back to the original role (the one that deleted the record in table B).
Is this expected?
If so, how do I allow edits if the role is postgres even after the record is inserted?
BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE parent (id INT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(100));

CREATE TABLE child (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_id INT DEFAULT 0,
    edited_by text,
    CONSTRAINT fk_parent FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent (id) ON DELETE SET DEFAULT
);

CREATE TABLE logs ("text" text);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION react_on_child_update () RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO logs ("text") VALUES (CURRENT_role::text);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_before_react_on_child_update BEFORE
UPDATE ON child FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION react_on_child_update();

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_after_react_on_child_update
AFTER UPDATE ON child FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION react_on_child_update();

INSERT INTO parent (id, name) VALUES (0, 'ghost');
INSERT INTO parent (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Parent 1');
INSERT INTO parent (id, name) VALUES (2, 'Parent 2');
INSERT INTO child (id, parent_id) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO child (id, parent_id) VALUES (2, 2);

CREATE ROLE "user";
GRANT ALL ON TABLE parent,logs,child TO "user";
SET ROLE TO "user";

DELETE FROM parent
WHERE id = 1;

SELECT * FROM parent;
SELECT * FROM child;

-- See that first role was the admin one, the second the caller ("user")
SELECT * FROM logs;


What you describe sounds like Row-Level Security - you could try to use that instead. You can check the difference between current_role/current_user/user and session_user. By default functions use security invoker and you can change that to security definer, although that might be opposite of what you're looking for. You could also try to make the trigger pass the current_user as an argument to the function, then read it from TG_ARGV[0] inside it or check it earlier in trigger..where condition.

My point is to do something like "if the origin of the UPDATE trigger (because we're updating the FK to default) is the deletion of the referenced FK, allow all BEFORE/UPDATE triggers". So I don't really run any function

The issue is from here CREATE TRIGGER: ... or after the operation has completed (after constraints are checked and the INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE has completed) .... By the time you get to an AFTER trigger it too late to do anything, the role really does not enter into it.


Which role is responsible for performing ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT in PostgreSQL

The owner of the constraint, which by extension has to also be the owner of the table it's on. There's no "system role", things are just owned by regular roles and things they set up can be traced back to them.

the physical "change" of the original FK for the default value is apparently done by the "system role" (in my case postgres)

I'm guessing the role postgres just owns that table. If someone_else owned it, you'd see the update being run by them instead - postgres isn't special, it just happens to be their table and their constraint. You can check it in pg_tables:
select tableowner
from pg_tables
where tablename='child';


turned to work when the trigger is "BEFORE UPDATE" and not "AFTER UPDATE". in other words, based on my observations, the moment the records gets physically updated, the db changes the executing role back to the original role

It shouldn't matter. If you check the current_user and based on that raise exception in the after trigger, this will cause the entire chain of events to be invalidated just as well as if it was thrown before, after or instead of.
As to the visibility: even if you set the before trigger function to security invoker, the update caused by referential integrity constraint cascade action is issued as the owner of that constraint, so the function is also invoked by them. That's what current_role shows both in the context of trigger..when() as well as inside the function that it proceeds to execute:
demo at db-fiddle



event
op
schema
table
current_user
session_user
trigger_arg0




BEFORE
UPDATE
public
child
owner
owner
param of the trigger BEFORE update function call


AFTER
UPDATE
public
child
not_owner
owner
param of the trigger AFTER update function call



In order to see who caused that cascading update to run from inside the trigger it fired, you could check the session_user and use that to allow/reject that update - that remains untouched even for the update resulting from cascade.
Problem is, the owner that operates under set role not_the_owner, would still get identified as the owner. And vice versa: someone connected as not-the-owner but switched to owner mid-session, still gets rejected unless they reconnect as the owner.
The create constraint trigger..after update idea should work fine (here's user failing to remove the parent, here's the owner succeeding). With security invoker (default), the function will run under the current_user role and from there, you can raise to prevent the cascaded update, or run a different one if that's what you want. Make sure to check new/old values and compare them to the default inside when() to avoid falling in a loop where this new update triggers another update and so on.

I replicated your case study and got postgres as the credential in the update according to your commands. But that's because I'm logged to the data base as such. Not sure I understand the purpose of this test.

The purpose is to demostrate the (unexpected) role switch after performing the update to the table. The "logs" table should have two records -> postres, user
